# Async/await with a task, refactoring method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

In the below .net code is the async/await needed when there is also a task in the method?

transaction.execute returns a string which is then returned by the method. This is a slow running method.

I know async/await runs on the main thread using a state machine and that the task will run on a threadpool thread.

Whats the best way to refactor this method or is it ok the way it is?

```
  public async Task<string> ExecuteTransaction(ITransaction transaction)
  {
        var task = new Task<string>(transaction.Execute);

        task.Start();

        var taskResult = await task;

        return taskResult;
  }
```

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing stay absolutely away from `var task = new Task<string>(transaction.Execute); task.Start();`

Comment: Why do you say that out of interest?

Comment: There are many reasons. First one is performance though, Second one is it introduces mistakes and synchronization problems. There are cases where you want to use `Start`. Have a look at here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/14/faq-on-task-start/

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify it greatly with [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
public Task<string> ExecuteTransactionAsync(ITransaction transaction) {
    return Task.Run(transaction.Execute);
}
```

In the above case there really is no reason to keep the await, but in a scenario where you need to invoke code after the task

```
public async Task<string> ExecuteTransactionAsync(ITransaction transaction) {
    var taskResult = await Task.Run(transaction.Execute);

    //...

    return taskResult;        
}
```

Comment: Thats great. How would a version using async/await look?